# How to make one solid object in Maya?

Tags: objects

How can I "glue" more objects to each other so I get one object? (It is for resizing models), couldn't find anything about it on the internet, but I'm dutch, so maybe that's why. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them to be resized, moved, and rotated together, use Grouping. Just select all of the models and click Edit->Group. This will allow them to be edited together.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, this will help me alot. I'm sorry I'm still a noob on this site, I need 15 rep to vote you up, so I can't, I'm sure somebody else will. THANKS!!

Comment: there's your 15 rep :)